# Miscrosoft Excel create string from combined columns

Tags: excel

I have the following data in Excel:

Columns 1
(text 1)

Columns 2
(text 2)

I would like to have in columns 3:
( text1 & text2 )

So column 3 would have all the combined values from column1 and column 2. I am a rookie in Excel how would I go about doing this?

Example result:

```
Column 1--+-Column 2--+-Column 3
george    | costanza  | (george costanza)
jerry     | seinfeld  | (jerry seinfeld)
cosmo     | kramer    | (cosmo kramer)
elaine    | benez     | (elaine benez)
```

Comment: @pnuts what if I need this for every column?

Comment: stick that formula in one column3 first row and drag it down to all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Use [Concatenation function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) from Office Excel.